# Cribbage scoring for one hand less starter card

Tags: cribbage

What would be the score count for a hand with 3 - fours and 1 - seven
my thought is 12.  For 3 - fours equal 6 points (3 royal pairs) and the three royal pairs of 2-fours and the seven = 6 points.

Answer (score 3):

If I read you correctly, you're describing a hand like 4H 4D 4S 7D.

- 4H 4D 7D - 15 2
- 4H 4S 7D - 15 4
- 4D 4S 7D - 15 6
- 4H 4D - pair (2 points)
- 4H 4S - pair (2 points)
- 4D 4S - pair (2 points)

You are indeed correct that this adds to 12 points. You are also correct that you can shortcut the pairs to 6 points as Pair Royal.